# Creating Generic class object using CreateInstance

Tags: generics, activator, createinstance

I have following code sample

```
public interface ITest
{
    string abc { get; set; }
}

public class GenericController<T> :  Controller  where T : class, ITest, new()
{
    public string abc { get; set; }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        return View();
    }
}
```

Now trying to create object with following code gives me error -

```
Type typeObject = typeof(Employee);
Type object1 = typeof(GenericController<>).MakeGenericType(typeObject);
controller = (IController)Activator.CreateInstance(object1);
```

Error given is

> GenericArguments[0], 'MvcApplication2.Controllers.Employee', on 'MvcApplication2.Controllers.GenericController`1[T]' violates the constraint of type 'T'.

Removing the ITest interface from GenericController class works properly. I need that interface so type casting the controller object to interface I can set few properties of the newly created object.

How to fix this issue.

-Rajesh

Comment: I found the solution for same.

Class should be written with following statement  class 
public class GenericController<T> :  Controller, ITest  where T : class, new()

-Rajesh

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your `Employee` implements `ITest`??
If it works without `ITest` on the GenericController and it says `violates constraint`, then, conclusion is you are passing a Type that does not implement `ITest`.